# How can linux system boot/reboot without bootloader installed?

Tags: boot, grub, boot-loader

Today I saw that grub is missing on my system (how that happened is another question). Checked with apt/dpkg: no grub* package installed, also no lilo or systemd-boot package installed.
Also was looking for grub or the like in bootsector: `dd if=/dev/xvda1 bs=512 count=1 | strings`, no result...
I have snapshot that I can return to in case of system failure, so I did `sudo shutdown -r now`, and the system rebooted fine!!!

My question is: How is this possible???
To my limited IT knowledge you MUST have a bootloader in order to boot a system, I am confused!

(My machine: vServer running under Xen; Debian 11 x64 installed; single boot, no other OS on disk)

Comment: There is no bootloader needed for Xen paravirtual domU, neither it needs its kernel image to exist inside the domU as a file. In that case hypervisor itself loads the domU kernel from its own store and gives it a kick.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Amazing! Thank You. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.